# Vector of structs with using structs out of other class

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I need to create and use vector with structs of other class.

So class **Scanner** contains following struct structure:

```
class Scanner
{
    struct structOneScan
    {
        unsigned int X_MULTIPLE_POS[290];
        unsigned int Z_MULTIPLE_POS[290];
        unsigned int I_MULTIPLE_COUNT[290];
    }
  structOneScan SnapsArray[3000] ;
};
```

in Draw.cpp i manipulate this struct:

```
if (Counter<3000)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 290; i++)
    {
         Scanner.SnapsArray[Counter].X_MULTIPLE_POS[i] = (double) (Scanner.X_POS[i] * X_Factor);
         Counter ++;
    };
```

Now that i have the information copied in my SnapsArray, i need to analyse this information and save it in a vector, cause there can be many such Scans.
Thats why i create another class CMeasurementResult, to save the structs in a vector:

```
#include "CScanner.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CMeasureResult
{

public:
   vector<structOneScan*>Scans;
};
```

but the way i try it doesn´t work. Also tried it over a Pointer from Scanner, but it doesn´t work too.
vectorScans; doesn´t work too.

vectorScans; ist the declaration. Qualifier 'scanner' is not a name of a class or namespace. Tempaltespecification out of 'vector<_Ty,_Ax>' can´t be generated. Sorry for bad translation, my compiler is in German language. So if I compile, this ist the Error. C++ Builder Embarcadero

Comment: Off topic: Style suggestion: replace `3000` with a `constexpr size_t SnapsArraySize = 3000;` so you don't have to go hunting for `3000`s should you ever decide to change to, say, `5000`. Same for the `290`s.

Comment: `vector<structOneScan*>Scans;` looks like it should be `vector<Scan::structOneScan*>Scans;`

Comment: Also doesn´t work. And Thanks for first  comment, i will change it in my code

Comment: Could you edit your question to expand on "Doesn't work?". If it doesn't compile, also provide the error messages. If it compiles but doesn't run as expected, what does it do?

Comment: What did you try to save them?

Comment: vector<Scanner::structOneScan*>Scans; ist the declaration. Qualifier 'scanner' is not a name of a class or namespace. Tempaltespecification out of 'vector<_Ty,_Ax>' can´t be generated. Sorry for bad translation, my compiler is in German language. So if I compile, this ist the Error. C++ Builder Embarcadero

Comment: @MikeCAT I can´t even save anything...

Comment: @LamaDingo Are you sure you defined `Scanner`, not `Scan`?

Comment: @MikeCAT Yeah I just copied it out of my code and put here as a comment

Comment: Your definition of `Scan` lacks required semicolon.

Comment: @LamaDingo Please don't add codes as comment. Please edit your question to add ones.

Comment: @MikeCAT Scan and missing ; were an error of my typing...sorry

Comment: Scanners was a *great* movie! :))